# Which transaction manager will be used in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions

I am going through the transactions exist in WCF service but seeking some more clarification on this. I am not sure about which transaction manager WCF will use for following scenarios:

1. If the WCF service is performing insert in table of one SQL server database and delete from table of another SQL server database (in same or different server)
2. If the same WCF service is performing insert in table of one SQL server database and delete from table oracle database.
3. If WCF service calling 2 different WCF service performing operation on same SQL server base database.

Kindly help me providing some understanding on this situations.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're giving WCF more credit than it's due.  WCF can do some amazing stuff, but there's nothing magical about it.  It provides a set of interfaces for web services and allows you to provide an intermediary access layer for your data.

So let's tackle your scenarios:

> 1. If the WCF service is performing insert in table of one SQL server database and delete from table of another SQL server database (in same or different server)

We've got two RDBMS in use here, so you're going to have two transaction managers.  The first transaction manager is in the RDBMS for the insert, and the second transaction manager is for the delete.

> 2. If the same WCF service is performing insert in table of one SQL server database and delete from table oracle database.

Again, we've got two RDBMS in use here, so you're going to have two transaction managers.  The first transaction manager is in the RDBMS for the insert, and the second transaction manager is for the delete.

Note that we don't need to care about which type of RDBMS it is, we just track the number that are involved.

> 3. If WCF service calling 2 different WCF service performing operation on same SQL server base database.

This one is a little trickier because we don't know what the 2 WCF services are doing, and there *is* some unadvisable voodoo magic that could be done to coordinate transactions across the 2 services.  I'm going to assume you're smarter than that and didn't mean that case.

So in this case, we have 1 RDBMS performing 2 separate transactions.  We'll have 1 transaction manager from the 1 RDBMS, but the operations will complete under different transactions.

---

*To wrap that up* - to know how many transaction managers are involved, you need to look at the number of RDBMS that are being used.  And to know how many transactions will be required, you need to look at the number of operations performed.

Notice that the use of WCF has no bearing on your concern about the managers.  WCF just happens to be a tool that provides an additional way of accessing the data through a service.  WCF is cool, but it's not magic.

---

*Additional note*
You asked in a comment:

> my concern is that in all of this condition which transaction manager it will use a) The LTM b) The KTM c) The DTC?

And for the MS SQL Server transactions, it will either be the LTM or the DTC that handles the transaction.  Per this [MSDN Blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/florinlazar/archive/2005/05/12/416805.aspx), it's not necessarily something you need to worry about until performance becomes a significant issue.  And you should avoid premature optimization in favor of getting things working first.

And based upon [this description of the KTM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's very unclear how you think you'd be using the KTM in any of the cases you asked about.

> The Kernel Transaction Manager (KTM) enables the development of applications that use transactions. The transaction engine itself is within the kernel, but transactions can be developed for kernel- or user-mode transactions, and within a single host or among distributed hosts.

Also note that Oracle DB has a separate transaction manager for its RDBMS that is different than the MS SQL Server transaction manager(s).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my concern is that in all of this condition which transaction manager it will use a) The LTM b) The KTM c) The DTC